# Searching For a Nested Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-5

I am wanting to know if it possible to search for an objects ID.

Ideally I want the search to redirect to the objects edit page however that has been problematic. I am rather now just searching on the index page to try and show only the searched for object.

As it stands the index page opens with the full collection objects and when an ID is entered into the search bar is does clear the index but it does not show the appropriate object.

Here is my controller:

```
 def index
    @guests = @event.guests
    if params[:search]
      @search_term = params[:search]
      @guests = @event.guests.search_by(@search_term)
    end
  end
```

Here is my Guest model:

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event

  def self.search_by(search_term)
    where("(id) = :search_term", search_term: "%#{search_term}%")
  end
end
```

This is my index page:

```
<h3>Enter your ID here:</h3>
<%= form_for "", url: event_guests_path, role: 'search', method: :get do %>
<%= text_field_tag :search, @search_term, placeholder: "Enter ID here:" %>
<% end %>
<% @guests.each do |guest| %>
  <tr>
    <td> <%=guest.name %></td>
    <td> <%=guest.response %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', event_guest_path(@event, guest) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'RSVP', edit_event_guest_path(@event, guest) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Remove Guest', [@event,guest], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

If any more code is require I will update accordingly

thanks in advance

Comment: Are you still needing help with this?

Comment: @JonathanBennett Yes please

Comment: I've added some more details to the answer bellow about linking the nested resource back up via an email. Let me know if that clears everything up, or if you are still needing additional details. If you are looking for more, let me know where you are running into a problem. Even better if you add the details to the question!

Comment: Thanks @JonathanBennett, Much appreciated. I have relooked at my question and can see that i really didn't give much detail (new stack overflower) but I have now updated the question to be more specific.

Comment: Did the update in that last answer work for you or is this still a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are searching for an ID you do not want to use the `.find` method that you would using in the show/edit/update methods. To allow searching, in your controller you would want to do something like:

```rb
class EventsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        # all your normal stuff for getting @events

        if params[:search]
            @events = @events.where('id LIKE ?', params[:search])
        end
    end

end
```

In you index.html.erb file you will want to have a form the lets you search, and you can optionally show the results with a direct link to the edit page:

```html
<%= form_tag events_path, method: :get %>
    <div class="classes-etc">
        <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% if @events do %>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      ...
      <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @events.each do |events| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= event.name %></td>
        ...
        <td>
          <%= link_to 'Show', event_path(event) %>
          <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_path(event) %>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<% end %>
```

Typically on an index page you would link to the show action, ie `<%= link_to event.title, event_path(event) %>`. To have this link to the edit page of a resource instead you would use `<%= link_to event.title, edit_event_path(event) %>`.

If you are wanting to control where a user goes in a controller you can use the same method to change the URL (`event_path` vs `edit_event_path`) when you are doing a `redirect_to`. With this you could create and RSVP and then redirect to the edit page via `redirect_to edit_rsvp_path(@rsvp)` in the controllers create method.

---

Upon rereading your question, I see that I haven't addressed the RSVP part. For that, my recommendation would be to have a `Reservation` be a nested resource under the event. This would allow you to create an `event` with `has_many :reservations` in it:

```rb
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  ...
  resources :event do
    resources :reservation, only: [:create, :update] # you might want more, this will give you an address like: site.com/events/123/reservations 
  end
  ...
end

class ReservationsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @reservation = @event.reservations.build(event_params)

    @reservation.confirmed = false 
    @reservation.confirmation_code = compute_confirmation_code(@reservation) # this will be in the email link to make sure the email link is valid, if you care about that

    if @reservation.save
      ReservationMailer.confirmation_email(@reservation).send_later 
      redirect_to @event
    else 
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    @reservation = Reservation.find(params[:id])

    if @reservation.confirmation_code == compute_confirmation_code(@reservation)
      @reservation.confirmed = true
      @reservation.save
      redirect_to @reservation.event, flash: { success: "Reservation confirmed" }
    else
      redirect_to @reservation.event, flash: { error: "Reservation invalid for reasons etc" }
    end
  end

  private
  def compute_confirmation_code(reservation)
    reservation + 42 # this would usually be a hash or something 
  end
end

class ReservationMailer < ApplicationMailer

  def confirmation_email(reservation)
    @event = reservation.event
    @reservation = reservation

    mail(to: @reservation.email, subject: "Confirmation for #{@event.name}")
  end
end
```

Your email template would look something like this, note using the `event_reservation_url` not `event_reservation_path` route helpers:

```
<%# app/views/reservation_mailer/confirmation_email.text.erb %>
Hello,

You are registering for <%= @event.name %>. 

Click here to confirm your email: <%= event_reservation_url(@event, @reservation) %>.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have the controller, if you've done a search with a single result, redirect:

```rb
def index
  @guests = @event.guests
  if params[:search]
    @search_term = params[:search]
    @guests = @event.guests.search_by(@search_term)
  end

  if params[:search] && @guests.count == 1
    redirect_to edit_guests_path(@guest.first)
  end
end
```

Additionally, in your `search_by` function, you are currently generating sql that will look something like `WHERE (id) = '%1234%'`, where you are using `=` to test not `LIKE`, or are adding %s to the string which are not needed. Either way, that explains getting no results. You probably want to change it to `where("(id) LIKE :search_term", search_term: "%#{search_term}%")` or `where("(id) = :search_term", search_term: search_term)`. The later can be written in a more Rails-ish way: `where(id: search_term)`.

Comment: The reason I am using the '=' is because with the LIKE test if I enter ID of 1, it returns every guest back where the ID contains a 1. I have a feeling that the '=' test is not returning anything back due to the ID being an integer and the search term being a string?

Comment: Ahh, I see. Its because you are adding the %s to the ID number so its looking for literally `%1%` which I assume is not what your IDs look like. I've updated my answer to reflect this.